# i keep getting error 404 error whenever running a file in local host

Tags: apache, xampp, http-status-code-404

i am using xampp and i stored all my code in a folder called Code which is stored in a folder called htdocs, in xampp. When I put localhost/Code/footer.php into my web browser, it gives an error 404 error, saying error 404, object not found. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: yes, I have a file called footer.php

Comment: Are you running IIS or any other web server that might be interfering with port 80? Have you changed your port configuration for Apache to something other than 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing `http://localhost` .

Does it give you a 404 page? If it doesn't, it means there is something wrong with either your file names (special characters) or you have placed the file in another sub-directories.

If it gives you a 404 page, it means you didn't setup xampp properly. Check if you have apache service turned on at xampp control panel.

Let me know if you're still facing issues.

Comment: I think my problem is the file i am calling is not in the xampp file i want to run. how do i put the file into xampp so i can run it?

Comment: Are you using Netbeans? Try going into htdocs and extract out all the files. Place them into a folder that you wanna call it (Code in this case) and remove all other sub-directories. Your file must be something like this: /Code/index.php. Remove away all other folders (nbproject or something like that)

Delete the project from Netbeans completely including the sources and copy paste the codes back into the htdocs. Create a new project with existing sources and browse to your project. It should be able to work now.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think there is another Webserver listening on port 80 and respond on your requests.

Solution: -

Stop the other webserver if you want to use XAMPP is the easiest way. Search for any Apache processes in your task managers processes tab and any Apache Services in your Windows Services.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that it needs to be a directory underneath `xampp/`?

Why not move up to `htdocs` and add a virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\Code
    ServerName code.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Of course you'd have to add a new entry to your *hosts* file for this too.

```
127.0.0.1  code.localhost
```